# Limit execution of a custom task to execution of bootBuildImage

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I've grown tired of manually incrementing the version number of the docker image that I'm building in my project. I've therefore written a small script, that does that task for me, it looks like this:

```
group = 'XXXXXXXXX'
version = '1.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

task incrementVersion {
    def v = version
    String minor=v.substring(v.lastIndexOf('.')+1) //get last digit
    int m=minor.toInteger()+1                      //increment
    String major=v.substring(0,v.lastIndexOf("."))       //get the beginning
    String s=buildFile.getText().replaceFirst("version = '$version'","version = '"+major+ "." +m+"'")
    buildFile.setText(s) //replace the build file's text
}
```

It does work fine and increments the version number, but not only, when I tell gradle to `bootBuildImage`. I'm using IntelliJ, and it seems IntelliJ checks up on the build.gradle and goes through it to make sure that the changes are alright, and not broken. However this also triggers my increment task, which again alters the file, and retriggers the checkup... you see where this is going.

I now got a constantly increasing version number, every time IntelliJ retries to assert a good build.gradle file. I now need to make sure, that my custom task "incrementVersion" is ONLY executed, when I trigger the bootBuildImage task.

If this is not possible easily, I'd also be fine with disabling the auto-checkup of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task consists mainly of some configurations and some actions. Task configuration can happen even if it is not going to be executed. However, actions only run during task execution.

When you put code directly in the closure given to the task, it is to *configure* the task. So your code can potentially be executed even if you just type `gradlew help`.

What you probably wanted to do is move it to the task actions. To do that, just wrap it in a `doFirst` or `doLast` method:

```java
// Groovy DSL

task incrementVersion {
    doFirst {
        // Your code here
    }
}

// Or better yet (using lazy APIs):

tasks.register("incrementVersion") {
    doFirst {
        // Your code here
    }
}

bootBuildImage.dependsOn("incrementVersion") // Assuming you have something like this as well
```

Comment: Did work out, just had to understand it properly ^^' Thank you very much :)